# Dot product of projection and vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $P$ is a plane and $x$ is a vector (both in $\mathbb{R^3}$), can we say that
>
> $$x \cdot \text{proj} _{P}x = 0$$

For the dot product, must  it always be $0$?

Comment: Let $x$ be a vector on the plane $P$. Then the projection of $x$ on $P$ must be equal to $x$. Hence $x \cdot \text{proj}_Px = x \cdot x$. But $x \cdot x$ is never zero if $x \neq 0$. So, what you are saying is not always true. In fact, it is usually false.

Comment: The only case I can think of that this would be true is if $x$ was perpendicular to $P$.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it. If p is some non-zero vector, the projection of u onto p is usually given by $$\frac{u\cdot{p}}{|p|^2}p$$ then, 
$$
u\cdot{\frac{u\cdot{p}}{|p|^2}p}
$$
But we can see that $\frac{u\cdot{p}}{|p|^2}$is just a scalar that we can factor out of the dot product, thus we are left with
$$
\frac{u\cdot{p}}{|p|^2}u\cdot{p}=\frac{(u\cdot{p})^2}{|p|^2}
$$
Which is zero if and only if $u\perp p$.